# Best practice for ion tags

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a bit confused about tag usage in the ionic framework. If you check their docs under [CSS components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/), you'll see they use existing tags (particularly div) with a specific class choice to achieve formatting, just like you'd expect from something like bootstrap. Example:

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
  <h1 class="title">bar-light</h1>
</div>
```

If you go by their [code samples](http://codepen.io/ionic/public-list/), however, you see that they use custom ion tags instead. Example:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
  <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

The same practice of using custom ion tags is used in their [guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html) as well as a pluralsight tutorial I found on ionic.

So what's going on here? If both approaches accomplish the same thing, which one is considered best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic Framework, as stated in their [site](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/), is:

> Ionic is both a CSS framework and a Javascript UI library. Many
>   components need Javascript in order to produce magic, though often
>   components can easily be used without coding through framework
>   extensions such as our AngularIonic extensions.

Using [CSS Components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/) you're simply applying CSS styling to your HTML page.

When using the Ionic directives you're using a fully-featured JavaScript component and you have access to the APIs provided by the framework.

To better understand the difference you should dig into [AngularJs directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Take the list for example. You could create a simple [list](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list) using an HTML `ul` `li`:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

but if you use the [directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/):

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    Hello, {{item}}!
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

you have access to the extended features provided by the framework (see the [API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/) at the bottom of the page).

I tend to use directives most of the times unless I know I don't want any kind of interaction with the interface.